# ApplicationContext failed to load

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito, junit4

I am new to testing. I have created a test case to perform a test on rest API using JUNIT Mockito. In my code I have created a test on method itemGetByid(), but when I run the test I get ApplocationContext error message. I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
Item Controller Test class
    package com.example.demo.controller;

    import com.example.demo.entities.Item;
    import com.example.demo.entities.User;
    import com.example.demo.service.ItemService;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import java.util.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

    @WebMvcTest(ItemController.class)
    public class ItemControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        MockMvc mockmvc;
        @Mock
        ItemService itemService;
        @InjectMocks
        ItemController itemController;

        @Test
        public void itemGetById() {

            Item item = new Item();
            Mockito.when(itemController.getById(10L)).thenReturn(item);
            Item i = itemController.getById(10L);
            assertEquals(i, item);

        }
    }

    Item entity class
    package com.example.demo.entities;

    import lombok.Data;
    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Item")
    public class Item {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long itemId;
        private Long customerId;
        private String itemName;
        private int itemPrice;

    }
    Item controller
    package com.example.demo.controller;

    import com.example.demo.entities.Item;
    import com.example.demo.entities.User;
    import com.example.demo.service.ItemService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("item")
    public class ItemController {

        private ItemService itemService;

        @Autowired
        public ItemController(ItemService itemService) {
            this.itemService = itemService;
        }

        @PostMapping("/post")
        public Item post(@RequestBody Item item) {
            return itemService.post(item);
        }

        @GetMapping
        public Iterable<Item> getAll() {
            return itemService.get();
        }

        @GetMapping("/get")
        public Item getById(Long id) {
            return itemService.getItem(id);
        }

        @DeleteMapping("/delete")
        public void deleteAll() {
            itemService.deleteAll();
        }

    }

    Item Service
    package com.example.demo.service;

    import com.example.demo.entities.Item;
    import com.example.demo.userepository.ItemRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

    @Service
    public class ItemService {
        ItemRepository itemRepository;

        @Autowired
        public ItemService(ItemRepository itemRepository) {

            this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
        }

        public Item post(@RequestBody Item item) {
            return itemRepository.save(item);
        }

        public Iterable<Item> get() {
            return itemRepository.findAll();
        }

        public void deleteAll() {
            itemRepository.deleteAll();
        }

        public Item getItem(Long id) {
            return itemRepository.findById(id).get();
        }

    }

    Item Repository
    package com.example.demo.userepository;

    import com.example.demo.entities.Item;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide information about actual exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you are using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. Try the MockitoJunitRunner.
An ItemController instance is never created in the test, so that needs to be fixed as well.
The line below will fail because itemController is not a mock.

```
**Mockito.when(itemController.getById(10L)).thenReturn(item);**
```

If itemController is converted to a mock, with the when statement, the test method doesnt validate anything because the test tells Mockito to return the item in the when statement.
Assuming the intent is to validate the ItemController getById method, the Mockito.when statement needs to describe the call to the Mock ItemService.